# Infer class constructor arguments from instance of class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a singleton class that is an extension of a 20x20 array.  (I'm making a word search.)  I discovered this delightful syntax for exporting a singleton class's instance maintaining both the name of the instance and that of the class:

```ts
const Grid = new class Grid extends Array<string[]> {
  constructor(private readonly size = 20) {
    super(size);
    // ...
  }

  // ...
};

export default Grid;
```

Huzzah, that works great.  Now to test.  To make things manageable, I want to create a new grid with a much smaller size (maybe 8x8).  In JavaScript, retrieving the constructor is easy.

```js
import Grid from './grid';

const GridConstructor = Grid.constructor;

it('does a thing', () => {
  const testGrid = new GridConstructor(8);
});
```

Since I *know* what the argument expects, yes, I can just do that and declare `GridConstructor` as

```ts
const GridConstructor: new(size: number) => typeof Grid = Grid.constructor;
```

That, of course, is the *reasonable* solution.  I am not a reasonable person though, and must type ALL THE THINGS using the TypeScript typing engine.  (Okay, so I really just like learning.  Who knows when this may be useful?)
TypeScript thinks that `Grid.constructor` is of type `Function`.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't have any information on what that function's shape is.

Is it possible to infer that shape?

The best I've come up with is:

```ts
type Constructor<T extends { constructor: new(...args: any[]) => any; }> = 
  new(...args: ConstructorParameters<T['constructor']>) => InstanceType<T['constructor']>;

const GridConstructor: Constructor<typeof Grid> = Grid.constructor;
```

This results in the error:

> `Type 'Grid' does not satisfy the constraint '{ constructor: new (...args: any[]) => any; }'.`

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA4gJwJYBMYF4ZgKYHcbAA2AhhBPMmtgB5TZgrkCCCCxAngDzTJgDmAbQC6APhgBvALAAoGAXA8ArsCggEACgAOyAG7E6MBNmIpwhdjAhIAXtgwwATAAYAlBJly5ERZuwarti4A3B4wAL4yEdIyUOy+MADCClAIyqoInAAqMDR0DOTi8pApaWoAXFh46gB0tcQIfBAVxGDswm7oYi0WYWLooTi4NXUNTYnJqSpqAAr1xAC22HQIEFkCAOSgxZPp66IdYgCSxS3A2Jlx2GubE6UIeyIh0dJb0BSoSdt3FZ9KUxmxXwgABm7xQfTB1VeJX+Txk0JgdGgiFQ9kGYN+MPS6gAHMEgA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a limitiation in TypeScript.  Class instances do not have strongly-typed `constructor` properties; as you noted, the compiler only sees its type as `Function`.  There is a quite longstanding open issue,
[microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841), asking for this to be changed.  But the "obvious" fix, where the compiler makes instances of a class named `Foo` have a `constructor` property of type `typeof Foo`, would break things.  It's explained in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841#issuecomment-163350868) by the language's architect:

> The general problem we face here is that lots of valid JavaScript code has derived constructors that aren't proper subtypes of their base constructors. In other words, the derived constructors "violate" the substitution principle on the static side of the class.

For example:

```
class Foo {
  x: string;
  constructor(x: string) {
    this.x = x.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Let's imagine that every value `foo` where `foo instanceof Foo` had a `constructor` property of type `typeof Foo`.  Then the compiler would allow you to write the following function without a type assertion:

```
function cloneFoo(foo: Foo): Foo {
  const ctor = foo.constructor as typeof Foo; // need assertion here in current TS
  return new ctor(foo.x); 
}
```

Then as long as you are just dealing with `Foo` itself, there wouldn't be a problem:

```
cloneFoo(new Foo("x")); // okay
```

But, JavaScript has `class` hierarchies where subclass constructors can require a different set of parameters than their base classes, and TypeScript also supports this:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  y: string;
  constructor(x: string, y: string) {
    super(x);
    this.y = y.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Here, `Bar`'s constructor requires a second parameter, while `Foo`'s does not.  But every instance of `Bar` is also an instance of `Foo`, according to both the [subtitutability principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and to the JS runtime (e.g., `new Bar("x", "y") instanceof Foo` evaluates to `true`).

But this leads directly to a problem.  If every `Bar` instance is also a `Foo` instance, then every `Bar` instance's `constructor` property must be a valid `typeof Foo`.  *But it isn't:*

```
cloneFoo(new Bar("x", "y")); // error at runtime! y is undefined
```

We've gained a strongly-typed constructor but got runtime errors in exchange.  To prevent these errors, you'd either need to give up on subclass instances being assignable to superclass instances, making `extends` a misnomer... or you'd have to restrict subclass constructors so that you could require the same parameters as the superclass, which would be a "massive breaking change" since plenty of existing JavaScript `class` hierachies violate this rule.

So while the current typing of `constructor` as just `Function` is kind of useless, it at least doesn't destroy either class hierarchies or the type system, which is nice.  It's possible there might be something better than `Function`, but not anything which you can  safely call with `new`.

Thus the issue has been sitting untouched for years.

---

Note that in your case, subclasses are not obviously a possibility, since you have a `private` property which makes things hard to extend.  So perhaps one could open a new issue (or comment on the existing one) asking that `constructor` be strongly-typed on any class with a `private` property.  In some sense this would be creating true `final` classes in TypeScript... but that has already been proposed and rejected in [microsoft/TypeScript#8306](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306).

Anyway, for now, this is the way it is.

---

If *you* know it's safe to use a strongly-typed `constructor`, then a type assertion is a reasonable solution; but this is tantamount to what you're already doing:

```
const GridConstructor = Grid.constructor as new (size?: number) => typeof Grid;
```

Another workaround here is to manually *declare* a strongly-typed `constructor` property:

```
const Grid = new class _Grid extends Array<string[]> {
  ["constructor"]: typeof _Grid
  constructor(private readonly size = 20) {
    super(size);
  }
}
```

(The quotes and brackets around `constructor` are necessary to avoid errors... and the rename from `Grid` to `_Grid` is not necessary but helps avoid confusion about which thing we're talking about).

Of course, this is hardly better than a type assertion; you are forcing yourself to write out the constructor type yourself.

---

So I'd say the answer here is just **no**; the compiler intentionally does not allow you to infer the type of the constructor parameters from the type of an instance, and it's not clear when or if this will ever change.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```js
class Foo {
  x: string;
  constructor(x: string) {
    this.x = x.toUpperCase();
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('hello');

const foo2 = new (foo.constructor as any)("world")
```