# Get type of obj.constructor in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the keys of an object's constructor's prototype.

```ts
type PrototypeKeys<T> = T extends { constructor: { prototype: infer P } } 
  ? keyof P
  : never;

class Foo {
  foo() { return 1; }
}

const foo = new Foo();
type FooPrototypeKeys = PrototypeKeys<typeof foo>; // expect 'foo'

const bar = {
  foo() { return 1; }
};

type BarPrototypeKeys = PrototypeKeys<typeof bar>; // expect never
```

To my surprise, in both cases the resultant type is `string | number | symbol`.

I dug a little deeper and found that `typeof foo['constructor']` is `Function` not `Foo`.  Is there a way to retrieve the strongly typed constructor of an object?

I tried

```ts
type ConstructorOf<T> = T extends { constructor: infer C } ? C : never;
```

but this always returns `Function` as well (except for `null` and `undefined`).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge2E8EDSEQGcA8AVAPigF4o8oIAPYCAOwBMsoBvKAYwVq2DgFc3kcAFwsoYRMlCQRAS1oAzCHFhQAvmqgAoKFAD8UANaYE82NqgjaEAG5KA3Js1sANgEMsTAGIIELc-J8ACgBKUTgIYF44WigARjs1TVVHDi5gKADfUisAdyhvBBCHKWgC+CQUSAxsElgJSvRMXBKTDJ8CBIB6TopKSAEoAHJMwZTObigAI1dlUmZ-INDWcMjouITk5M0SqAAhGfLJVGqmUkOGk5wW02m4Dqhu3v70q1s4Rx2AYXGefkEAeXk+CIpHIVBoDCYrFS3D4AgQwigckUyk+Gn0aMsNnsQA)

Comment: No, you can't (at least not without manually annotating each class as having a `constructor` property of a particular type), see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841.  But even if you could this wouldn't work to give you prototype properties, since TypeScript represents the class constructor's `prototype` property as being of the instance type itself, so `type PrototypeKeys<T>` is going to be `keyof T` for any specific class which you could [test yourself](https://tsplay.dev/mpvQBw).  So, this is going to be a no-go unfortunately.

Comment: Sad times.  Alright.  Want to throw that into an answer?

Comment: I think [I've rambled about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64848758/2887218) so I won't go over that again here.  (The part about `prototype` is not really in scope of the question as asked, since you are specifically asking about getting a strongly typed constructor from an instance type.)

Comment: *Kind of*.  I see it as a different question than the one I asked that this was marked as a duplicate of.  In my previous question (which I'd forgotten I'd asked a year ago), I was specifically looking for the constructor arguments, but I can see how they technically have the same answer.

Comment: This could be reopened but they definitely have the same answer (which SO sometimes gets upset at me for, when I make a new answer that's too close to an existing answer elsewhere).